# Chrome Won't Search data list by Label

Tags: php, javascript, search, input

I have the following input box in my site, which I want to give suggestions by the Given Label, and when selected the Value is passed to the database for SQL.

```
<input type="text" name="Search" size="45px" placeholder="&nbsp;Search student records." list="StudentList">
<datalist  id="StudentList">
    <option value="145" label="Jake">
</datalist>
```

I'd Like suggestions to appear based on the label and not by Value, just like in Firefox.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var studentList = document.getElementById('StudentList');
var selectedLabel = studentList.options[studentList.selectedIndex].getAttribute('label');
```

EDIT:

html:

```
<input type="text" name="Search" size="45px" placeholder="&nbsp;Search student records." list="StudentList">
<datalist  id="StudentList">
    <option value="Jake" data-id="145">
</datalist>
```

js:

```
var search = document.getElementsByName('Search')[0];
var datalist = document.getElementById('StudentList')[0];
search.addEventListener('change', function(){
    var id;
    for(var i = 0; i < datalist.options.length; i++){
        if(datalist.options[i].value === this.value)
            id = datalist.options[i].getAttribute('data-id');
    }
    // Use id here to search
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to Reply
But I'm not Sure how I can use your answer. Though there was a spark in my mind, I'm not sure how I can activate or call the above Javascript.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: @user2128576 wait, i'll think about that (I misunderstood your question first time)

Comment: @user2128576 Edited answer, i hope it will help

Comment: Thank you So much sir it did great though I needed to change things :)
The reason why it took me long to mark it as answer is that I was making modifications to it.

Comment: Oh and I shouldn't have called you "sir" since I do not know if your a guy or a girl :)
Anyways thank you for the really fast replies.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25607/discussion-between-user2128576-and-karaxuna)